# Beginner in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system

Ok...so I've just started playing around with Codeigniter. I've followed the two tuts on their website and I'm looking for more resources to expand my knowledge. What do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start writing an application using CI. You'll learn more than any tutorial will teach you...

Comment: that's the thing....I need to learn how to write an application. What king of app would you recommend? Maybe a simple login site?

Comment: You could do that, although there are already plenty of Auth packages out there that will do much of the login logic. You could always implement a "classic" web application like a blog.

Answer (score 3):

Nettuts' [CodeIgniter from Scratch](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/) series is really useful for beginners.

Other than that, like @Justin said, just make an app.

Answer (score 2):

You can also watch these two videos: http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/

You can also take a look at this tutorial which shows you how can you keep your controllers clean and non fat: http://chris-schmitz.com/cleaning-up-your-codeigniter-controllers/

Comment: Those two videos are a great resource to beginners. Really helped me get my head around things.